# Virtual Box rolling back on Win10

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install virtual box VirtualBox-5.1.38 on Windows 10 Ver. 1803 but its rolling back setup. I have tried older and latest version but no luck.
Tried to install through command prompt using msi with logs.  Can anyone please help me in this issue?

Sending some logs which shows failed -

1. DIFXAPP: ERROR:  Signature verification failed while checking integrity of driver package 'VBoxDrv.inf' ('C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.inf'). (Error code 0x800B0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.)

2.DIFXAPP: ERROR: InstallDriverPackages failed with error 0x800B0100

3.DIFXAPP: ERROR: Rollback failed with error 0x2

4.MSI (s) (60:DC) [12:38:50:616]: Product: Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.38 -- Installation failed.

Comment: Have you tried running setup as Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

- Right-click the VirtualBox installation file (.exe) and choose **Properties**
- Open the tab **Digital Signatures**
- Click on the displayed certificate
- Click **Details**
- Click **View Certificate**
- Click **Install Certificate ...**
- Follow the wizard

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall virtualbox and install the new version.

Don't fear, your VMs will not be deleted, [see here](https://superuser.com/a/1684821/1132403).