# How can I uninstall Oracle Virtual Box for good? Virtual machine images still present after uninstall

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I uninstalled Oracle Virtual Box with 5 VMs on it but when I reinstall it back, I still see the 5 VMs?

Comment: It is because the program `virtualbox` is stored in one location, while the images for the individual VMs is stored in a subfolder under your username home directory.

Comment: When you uninstall a video player, you usually don't want all your video files to be deleted. And if you install the player again, it will be able to play the files. Here the situation is similar.

Answer (score 2):

That's because uninstalling Virtual Box does not delete the virtual machine images you created while using it.

By default, VirtualBox stores its VM files in the folder `VirtualBox VMs` in the user's home directory (so, typically under `C:\Users\<username>\VirtualBox VMs` on MS Windows). To get rid of the VMs you created, you can delete these files (if you are certain you no longer need them).

Note that you can store your VM files in other locations, too, if you select a different location when creating the VM, or in the VirtualBox configuration. Then you'll have to look there.

See the documentation for details: [3.1. Where Oracle VM VirtualBox Stores its Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/vboxconfigdata.html)